# Update Badge in React Native Stack Navigator Header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, badge

[I have added badges in react native stack navigator for cart and wish-list count. These counts must be fetched from API on every screen change or back event. I also want to update these count on **add to cart** and **add to wish-list** event from Product screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk3ZH.png)

Can anyone suggests me how to do this ?
Any reference code or article will be very helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a need to update the UI globally from any screen of the app then we can implement global state management.

There are two simple ways to implement the global state which updates UI when changes made to it.

1. React Redux
2. React Context API

Use one of there and Make changes in the global state and assign the value to the UI Component the need for UI change is.

You can simply call an API and update the global state to update the badge count.

check out the official docs to implement the global state:

- For React Redux: https://react-redux.js.org/
- For Context API: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Can you share any code for react redux where this type of implementation is made ?